# InteliJ Vaadin Designer plugin causes infinite "scanning files to index"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, indexing, vaadin, vaadin-designer

I recently setup a new Spring Boot project using Maven, Java 21 and Vaadin 14.10.9. I use IntelliJ as my IDE. Because I am using Vaadin, I installed the "Vaadin Designer" pluging. When I try to open the project without this plugin enabled, everything works fine. However, as soon as I enable this plugin my project always gets stuck on "scanning files to index", seemingly making no progress (for several hours). This looks as follows:

[image]

Note that neither progress bar, be it the one in the middle or at the bottom, shows any sign of progress. They do have a small animation as if something is happening though. When I press 'cancel', IntelliJ continues as normal and I can run the program as usual. However, it does complain about installing several `npm` libraries that are already installed.

The last few entries of the idea.log file look as follows while the indexing is stuck:

```
...
2023-10-31 01:07:46,904 [  20845]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.EntitiesOrphanageImpl - Update orphanage. 0 modules added
2023-10-31 01:07:46,905 [  20846]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.WorkspaceModelImpl - Project model updated to version 10 in 7 ms: Root model commit
2023-10-31 01:07:46,922 [  20863] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.ApplicationImpl - AWT events are not allowed inside write action: java.awt.event.InvocationEvent[INVOCATION_DEFAULT,runnable=javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable@2f61d502,notifier=null,catchExceptions=false,when=1698710866849] on sun.awt.windows.WToolkit@2ab4392b
java.lang.Throwable: AWT events are not allowed inside write action: java.awt.event.InvocationEvent[INVOCATION_DEFAULT,runnable=javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable@2f61d502,notifier=null,catchExceptions=false,when=1698710866849] on sun.awt.windows.WToolkit@2ab4392b
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:370)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$postInit$0(ApplicationImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.runCustomProcessors(IdeEventQueue.kt:424)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:384)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:400)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupportKt.pumpEventsForHierarchy(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:379)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupportKt.access$pumpEventsForHierarchy(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport$runWithModalProgressBlockingInternal$2.invoke(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport$runWithModalProgressBlockingInternal$2.invoke(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:135)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ModalityKt.inModalContext(modality.kt:12)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport.runWithModalProgressBlockingInternal(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:135)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport.access$runWithModalProgressBlockingInternal(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport$runWithModalProgressBlockingInternal$1.invoke(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport$runWithModalProgressBlockingInternal$1.invoke(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ContextKt.prepareThreadContext(context.kt:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport.runWithModalProgressBlockingInternal(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.TasksKt.runWithModalProgressBlocking(tasks.kt:167)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtilKt.runUnderModalProgressIfIsEdt(ProjectUtil.kt:710)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.save(ProjectImpl.kt:364)
    at com.vaadin.designer2.intellij.editor.flow.NodeServerModuleComponent.lambda$indexNodeModules$1(NodeServerModuleComponent.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:992)
    at com.vaadin.designer2.intellij.editor.flow.NodeServerModuleComponent.indexNodeModules(NodeServerModuleComponent.java:96)
    at com.vaadin.designer2.intellij.editor.flow.NodeServerModuleComponent.lambda$indexNodeLater$0(NodeServerModuleComponent.java:70)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:208)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:861)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$4.run(ApplicationImpl.java:478)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:792)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:761)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$10(IdeEventQueue.kt:589)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithoutImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1485)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:589)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:369)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:992)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:992)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:861)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:405)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
2023-10-31 01:07:46,926 [  20867] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.ApplicationImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2  Build #IU-232.9921.47
2023-10-31 01:07:46,926 [  20867] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 17.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-10-31 01:07:46,927 [  20868] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.ApplicationImpl - OS: Windows 11
2023-10-31 01:07:46,927 [  20868] SEVERE - #c.i.o.a.i.ApplicationImpl - Plugin to blame: Vaadin Designer version: 4.6.23
2023-10-31 01:07:49,711 [  23652]   INFO - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexStorage - KCRI storage is closed (didn't exist)
2023-10-31 01:07:49,712 [  23653]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is closed (didn't exist)
2023-10-31 01:07:53,230 [  27171]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.IsUpToDateCheckStartupActivity - isUpToDate = true
2023-10-31 01:08:30,703 [  64644]   INFO - #c.i.u.g.s.GistStorageImpl - Cleaning old huge-gists dirs from [C:\Users\a98016721\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\caches\huge-gists] ...
```

When I click on 'cancel', the first few entries of the idea.log file that get added after the previous snippet are the following:

```
2023-10-31 01:13:32,859 [ 366800]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Module: 'CobotConnect'designer2.settings took 345895 ms
2023-10-31 01:13:32,946 [ 366887]   INFO - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexService - initialized
2023-10-31 01:13:32,952 [ 366893]   INFO - #c.i.l.j.l.t.TypeScriptExternalDefinitionsService - Type definition roots changed: project [CobotConnect], added/updated [], removed: [@types/lodash, @types/express]
2023-10-31 01:13:32,955 [ 366896]   WARN - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexStorage - kotlin-data-container is not found
2023-10-31 01:13:32,957 [ 366898]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - initialized
```

I have already tried:

- Deleting my .idea folder
- Invalidating Cache
- Waiting for several hours

Note that I have zScaler installed, for what it matters.

What could cause this issue and how would I go about resolving it?

Comment: Hello, in the error log, it seems something is wrong with the plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9519-vaadin-designer , I suggest you fire issues at https://github.com/vaadin/designer to let the plugin developers look into it.

Answer (score -2):

in idea.log, there is an error message about "java.lang.Throwable: AWT events are not allowed inside write action: java.awt.event.InvocationEvent[INVOCATION_DEFAULT,runnable=javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable@2f61d502,notifier=null,catchExceptions=false,when=1698710866849] on sun.awt.windows.WToolkit@2ab4392b"

I searched the browser for this error.

"AWT events are not allowed inside write action" error message typically indicates that an AWT event, such as a UI update, is being triggered from within a write action in a Swing application.

And this error in ApplicationImpl.java:182

Could that be the problem? You can check it first.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you search for something on the internet and then post it on Stack Overflow, you are required to post the source.  However, also keep in mind that the source [cannot be ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).  I'm guessing that the downvote on your answer is due to one of these problems.

Comment: Hello, the class you are referring to is not a class that is part of my project (probably some library or plugin?). Could you explain in more detail how I would solve this issue?